# how to solve the error of "no results matched the query" in Swift with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I try to add (detailsObj) into username_list if a product (title in the code) already exist in the class of "grouped_products"; otherwise, I would add a product into my class and (detailsObj) as well.
Everything works well, but the error of "no results matched the query" showed. It makes sense to me because if no results matched the query, I will add a product into my class. But, I don't know is there any way I can solve this error?

```
let detailsObj = PFObject(className: "products")
let title = 1 <<==(example)

 ........
let query = PFQuery(className: "grouped_products")
query.whereKey("title", equalTo: title)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (titleInParse: PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if titleInParse != nil{
        titleInParse!.addObjectsFromArray([detailsObj], forKey: "username_list")
        titleInParse?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            loadingNotification.hide(true)
            if (error != nil){
                self.appDelegate.displayMyAlertMessage(error!.localizedDescription, userVI: self)
                return
            } else {
                self.appDelegate.displayMyAlertMessage("Sent", userVI: self)
            }
        })
    } else if titleInParse == nil {
        let grouped_product = PFObject(className: "grouped_products")
        grouped_product["title"] = title
        grouped_product.addUniqueObject(detailsObj, forKey: "username_list")
        grouped_product.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil){
                self.appDelegate.displayMyAlertMessage(error!.localizedDescription, userVI: self)
                return
            } else {
                self.appDelegate.displayMyAlertMessage("Sent", userVI: self)
            }
        })
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PFQuery` documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) for `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:` states

> The block to execute. It should have the following argument signature: ^(PFObject *object, NSError *error). result will be nil if error is set OR no object was found matching the query. error will be nil if result is set OR if the query succeeded, but found no results.

Apparently that documentation is at least [partly wrong](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-pfquery-getfirstobjectinbackgroundwithblock-error-when-no-results) in regards to the error being `nil` for no found results.

Therefore you should probably use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead because if no match is found, the array will simply be empty but no `error` will be present (it will be `nil`).

If you still want to limit the results to just one you specify a `limit` of `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed  getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock to findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Now, it says addObjectsFromArray has  "value of type [PFObject] has no member 'addObjectsFromArray' and 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' as well. Is there any documentation I can find out which things I should use to replace addObjectsFromArray and saveInBackgroundWithBlock?

Comment: @PakHoCheung because now you actually retrieve an array with at max 1 element, get that element out - that will be the same as the previous `titleInParse` only without the error

Comment: I know it is a stupid question for you, but I am not sure which element I should get out. Sorry about that and thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, if I just want to insert the detailObj's id into the username_list. Any way I can do it?
I tried change detailObj to detailObj.objectId. It doesn't work. I guess it is because the Id has not generated by Parse yet. So, is detailObj a dictionary as what I see in Parse?
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"products","objectId":"bIkHx60rN0"}]
Also, I tried to search it in Parse. The thing I think I can use is like
myComment["parent"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"Post", objectId:"1zEcyElZ80")
But, for that one, I am wondering how I can obtain the objectId.
Thanks,